# react-native run-android Failed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, npm, build

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :@react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>
> Task :react-native-fbsdk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>
> Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>
> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
at runOnAllDevices (node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
```

Comment: configurations on Windows os building Android application
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.60.6
- node: v12.9.0
- npm: 6.10.2
- yarn: 1.22.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-native: 0.60.6 => 0.60.4, fixed it for me. Thanks.

for more details : [Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21722)

Answer (score 0):

#### Have you installed all the Environment Dependencies mentioned in the react-native docs? Use the below link

[Environment Setup for react-native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Go to the above link Select **Development and Target OS** and follow the instructions

Comment: I had followed all of that. but still not working. I think its version of react-native or node

Comment: What is OS you are using?

Comment: I am using windows os

Comment: I had updated the question to give more information